# Importing Bootstrap as SCSS in Rails 5.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, import, sass, bootstrap-4

I have a legacy Rails app which I'm trying to improve. I have a set of styles that I'd like to import and one of them is Bootstrap 4.

I have the following file `app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss`

Attempting to go `require_tree .` causes some errors so I'd like to go one-by-one starting with bootstrap.

In my Gemfile: `gem 'bootstrap'`

In the above mentioned `application.scss`:

```
/*
*= require_self
*/

// Bootstrap
@import 'bootstrap';
```

What's interesting is that although importing from this file/folder set "works" in that if something is off the app breaks but if all goes well like with the bootstrap import, on the actual website there is no `.css` file being imported.

### What's the tl;dr on setting up and importing sass files and the bootstrap library in Rails 5.2?

It should be so simple but I've been banging my head against a wall for hours now. Why don't the styles show up if they compile?

Is there an example of a site you can think of I can look at and see the diff which uses scss? It should be stupid simple but it's just not showing the result of compilation.

Comment: If all you need is CSS for Bootstrap then I've always found it easier to use a CDN than try to do it manually like you're doing. It helps your clients too; if it's in their cache from another site then your site will load faster. There are arguments for and against this approach, though.

Comment: @anothermh The rest (massive) styles are in scss so this is a no-go.

Comment: Do you have both `.scss` and `.css` files? Keep in mind that css is valid scss so all of the extensions should be changed. The most likely issue is mixing [import and require](https://github.com/rails/sass-rails#important-note) which can lead to multiple issues.

Comment: @MarkMerritt Please expand, it's unclear what you mean - are you talking about the url names and separate files or a single file?

Comment: Did you follow instructions of [README](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-rubygem#a-ruby-on-rails)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you mentioned rails 5.2 (NOT rails 6) then this below steps may work with your environment

inside your **app/assets/stylesheets/application.css**

```
/*
*= require_self
*= require main
*/
```

it's using css file but calling main.scss (which is located in same folder)

then inside **app/assets/stylesheets/main.css**
you can import any scss using import

```
// bootstrap
@import "bootstrap";
// basic scss 
@import "basic/bodi_and_font.scss";
@import "basic/datepicker.scss";
```

I'm using bootstrap 4 and above is some sample additional scss that I'm imported inside specific folder

Answer (score 0):

Rails 5.2 changes the way it handles target resulting files compiled by sprockets, it can be related to:

https://github.com/rails/sprockets/blob/master/UPGRADING.md